# How can I make the animation start again avoiding it to repeat code? jQuery

Tags: jquery, animation, duplicates, setinterval, clearinterval

When the first animation repeats the code is duplicated.

You can see the animation running [here](http://pruebas.joseama.com)

my code is as follows:
[here](http://pruebas.joseama.com/js/js.js)

I think the function ClearInterval is the one making the error, cause it starts the animation when the one playing before that it's still running

Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly then perhaps you want a function that calls itself after an interval?

e.g.

```
setInterval(animaciones, 1000);

function animaciones(){
    ...
    setInterval(animaciones, 1000);
}
```

if you want to display the next image every time you could do something like:

```
joseama.claseBarnners={     
    currentImage=1,
    ...

getNextImagePath:function(){
    var currentImagePath = "img/" + currentImage + ".jpg"
    currentImage = (currentImage % 3) + 1; // 1,2,3,1,2,3,1,
    return currentImagePath;
```

Comment: I've got no problem showing the next image, the thing is that when the animation 1 finish, and after the second one starts, inmediately the animation 1 appears again and the code inside the div "sliderContainer" duplicates. In resume, the problem appears when the function changes to execute the next animation.

Comment: What looks a little bit strange is that you have two functions defined called animaciones. One inside animacionLateral, and one inside animacionOpacidad. Possibly the code is getting confused which one should be called. Could you try renaming these functions as animaciones1, animaciones2 and declaring them in the same way you have declared animacionLateral:function() (except earlier in the module).

Comment: Thank you very much, and I found the fault. It was that there had put a code in a function and it breaks all programming